# INSERT with "IF" value empty?

Tags: php, sql, insert

Is it possible to use a statement like this:

```
$db->query("
   INSERT INTO database (field1,field2,field3, ...) 
   VALUES ($field1,$filed2, **IF(!empty($field2)){'$field3'}**, ...
)
```

VALUE is from `<INPUT>`.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to mix SQL and PHP together? You want the logic of PHP combined with the ANSI SQL statements from a database. Perform the logic first to create the INSERT statement.

Comment: Use prepared statements and provide the values you want to insert.

Comment: Maybe `coalesce` with `case .. is '' then null else`? Cant use PHP `empty` in mysql

Comment: Should tag the database as well.

Comment: You must first run the php commands like `if($_POST[VALUES]===NULL) then sql insert command` .
If you want to see if the cell is empty you need to run first the select command for sql and after the php like `if(empty(row['values'])) then again sql insert command`